# Convert ListView into LIstView.builder in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview, flutter-streambuilder

I want to convert this `ListView` into `ListView.builder`, but somehow I could not figure out how I could do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```dart
ListView(
  children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((doc) {
    final dynamic data = doc.data();
    return Visibility(
        child:
        ContactListTileField(
            text: data['contactName'].toString(),
            iconData: Icons.delete,
            function: () async {
              DialogBox.dialogBox(
                  "Do you really want to delete ${data['contactName'].toString().capitalize}? "
                  , context
                  , (){
                deleteContact(,context);
              });


            })

    );

  }).toList(),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ListView.builder(
      itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        final doc = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
        final dynamic data = doc.data();
        return  Visibility(
          child: ContactListTileField(
            text: data['contactName'].toString(),
            iconData: Icons.delete,
            function: () async {
              DialogBox.dialogBox(
                  "Do you really want to delete ${data['contactName'].toString().capitalize}? "
                  , context
                  , (){
                deleteContact(,context);
              });
            })
    );}
    )
```

Try this...

Comment: Thank You very much. It's work properly. And now I can understand how to convert ListView into ListView.builder.

Comment: @HashanRanasinghe If you find this answer useful, remember to mark it as accepted.